# ACF under category name in shop page

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using display categories only for shop page setup in woocommerce.
I added custom field (textfield) for product categories in Advanced custom fields.

I would like to display this text under category title on shop page (not on category page).

in content-product_cat.php after

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', $category );
```

I added:

```
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$post_id = 'product_cat_'.$term_id;
$custom_field = get_field('krotki_opis_kategorii', $post_id); // My Advanced Custom Field Variable
echo $custom_field;
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly here you want to display some text under each of the category titles on your shop page. Instead of editing the template i would suggest using a hook. To do this you should move your code into **functions.php**.

**The complete code would look something like this:**

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'wpse_add_custom_text_under_category_title', 10);

function wpse_add_custom_text_under_category_title($category) {
   $term_id = 'product_cat_'.$category->term_id;
   the_field('krotki_opis_kategorii', $term_id);
}
```

The reason why your code is not working is because when you run **get_queried_object_id** on the shop page it will return the id of the page and not the category. When you use the hook, the **$category** object will be passed in through the hook like in the code above.

Hope this was what you were looking for. I did not test this code but it should work.

Comment: works, thanks  !